# Serve Express.JS app from subfolder

Tags: node.js, nginx, express

I use nginx to serve a static html site and a expressjs app under the same domain. My nginx config looks like this:

```
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            autoindex  off;
            root /var/www/example.com/static/;
    }

    location /admin {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3007/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_buffering off;
            autoindex  off;
    }
```

I'm able to access my app running on port 3007 if i access example.com/admin so it seems that my `app.get('/', routes.index);` is working but I'm having some troubles getting my other routes to work.

For example:

```
app.get('/admin/test', function(req, res) {
    console.log("test!")
});
```

If I try to access `example.com/admin/test` I'll just see `Cannot GET //test` and a 404 according to my logs:

```
GET //test 404 11ms
```

If I change the route to /test it's the same problem. Any pointers what's wrong there. I haven't found a way to make routes relative to the base path they are mounted to (/admin).

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mind the slash:

```
location /admin {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3007/; # here
    …
}
```

If you remove it, the real request URI will be proxied.

You can also remove the `/admin` part with Nginx:

```
location ~ ^/admin($|/.*$) {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3007$1;
    …
}
```

Comment: Sometimes it's the little things that count most. Removing the slash did the track. Thanks for the fast (Almost too fast, I'll have to wait a couple of minutes before it's possible to accept it ;) ) reply!

Comment: Couldn't writing it as `/admin/?` do the same thing? I'm looking to do the same thing and wondering if this would also work.

Comment: @Bill: The `($|/.*$)` isn’t so much to allow an optional `/` (I think Nginx does this anyways) as to capture the part of the path after `/admin` so it can be given to `proxy_pass` (see the `$1` at the end). `proxy_pass http://localhost:3007` would result in the `/admin` being passed too.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thank you for clarifying. I appreciate the quick response to this pretty old question too.

Answer (score 0):

You can still retain your Nginx config code with the '/' (forward slash) and use `example.com/admin/test` to access test route.

```
app.get('//test', function(req, res) {
    console.log("test!")
});
```